# Scan Continuously for Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to **continuously scan for BLE Devices** but as many posts from the internet and many answers from StackOverflow, starting with Android N, Android prevents an app from stopping and starting BLE scan more than 5 times in a window of 30 seconds.

I am not concerned about battery usage as this is for a specific purpose and will be continuously powered by cable and it is not for a normal end user.

I am not able to find the working solution so far.

is there any workaround/trick to achieve this with reliability?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to stop and start scan that often? Your title says you want to scan continuously.

Also if you perform a filtered scan you can run it for how long time as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not have to stop it. I want to scan continuously for the indefinite time. I will give a try to a filtered scan.